# Use the output of find as the input for another command?

Tags: find, pipe, nm

I am looking for a specific symbol in a bunch of shared libraries, I am using the following command:

```
find . -iname "*.so" | nm -D //loop over output of find | grep -e symbol
```

How can I tell nm -D to loop over find results ? Thanks

Comment: Also see: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/237982)

Comment: find / -iname "*.so"  -exec nm -D {} \;  | grep -i symbol